# Enable or disable links when a route parameter is present or isn't present

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have routing that looks like this (removed the second param in `when()` to make it easier to read):

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    // Prepare for html5 mode
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    // Setup routing
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard/main', {
    }).when('/dashboard/website/:id/clicks', {
    }).when('/dashboard/website/:id/uploads', {
    }).when('/dashboard/website/:id/forms', {
    }).when('/dashboard/website/:id', {
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/dashboard/main'
    });

});
```

I then have navigation links, which I would then like to disable when `:id` is not present.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <!-- always active -->
    <li>
        <a href="/dashboard/main"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a>
    </li>
    <!-- active only if :id is set -->
    <li>
        <a href="/dashboard/clicks"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></i> Clicks</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

How can I make the second item enable itself when `:id` is present and disable itself when `:id` is not present?

Comment: try `ng-if='id !== undefined'` or some variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $routeParams inside the controller and check:

```
$scope.Options = $routeParams.id !== 'undefined'
```

And change the view to

```
<li ng-show='Options'>
        <a href="/dashboard/clicks"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></i> Clicks</a>
    </li>
```

Comment: I actually did this: `$scope.isDisabled = function(){
        return typeof $routeParams.id === 'undefined';
    };`

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `$routeParams` in your controller as

```
app.controller('yourControllerName', ['$routeParams', '$scope', function($routeParams, $scope){
$scope.isActive = inactive;
if($routeParams.id){
    $scope.isActive = active;
}
}]);
```

In your mark up,

```
<li data-ng-class="isActive">
        <a href="/dashboard/clicks"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></i> Clicks</a>
</li>
```

Then provide suitable styles for `.inactive` and `.active` classes using CSS